# Who is going to validate the inputs to my DAO?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dao

I'm new to enterprise design patterns. I have been told data access objects are not suppose to validate their inputs. If some other layer is suppose to perform the validation then wouldn't that layer need to know all of the database details, such as table names and so fourth? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having a DAO by breaking encapsulation?

Perhaps my understanding of the DAO responsibility is off and the service layer is also suppose to have knowledge of the database, but that seems odd. Currently I have my data access objects only performing CRUD operations.

**Note:** I'm using ordinary servlets, no MVC framework or persistence framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper implementation of a data access object should perform only crud operations. The only validation that should exist on the database are input constraints such as Unique indexes, foreign keys, Check Constraints, etc. Everything else beyond that should be handled by layers that interface with the DAO. Such constraints can be setup so that the db server performs them automatically before retrieving or updating a table. There is no need to put that into the logic of the DAO.

Answer (score 2):

A normal 3-tier application has an interface layer, a business layer and a data layer. The data layer is often a very thin cover over a database and generally doesn't do any validation other than sometimes it will validate string lengths for varchar columns.
Any *business* validation (such as not having numbers in usernames or not allowing spaces in passwords) would be done both on the interface layer (for performance reasons) and also in the business layer.
If you find a sample web application somewhere, they should hopefully demonstrate this fairly clearly.

Comment: What about validation that requires database knowledge, like whether or not an ID is unique, or whether or not a column input belongs to a set of allowable inputs?